# Two domains pointing on same site even though it shouldn't

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I've been trying to host 2 websites on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

The two domains are pointing to the first site (Bilbao-deco).

As you can see on my.conf file, my two document root are different.
I can't tell what I did wrong, I'll be glad if anyone could help !

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bilbao-deco.fr
    ServerAlias bilbao-deco.fr
    ServerAdmin nicolasalric@hotmail.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bilbao-deco.fr
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.nalric.fr
    ServerAlias api.nalric.fr
    ServerAdmin nicolasalric
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api/www/api_tub_ws/html
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.nalric.fr
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : my problem were caused by certbot, it made another conf file, which is not the default one !